# How should Rust unit tests be organised?

Tags: unit-testing, rust

I have a number of methods in a `mod`. These methods need to be tested but they're private. I currently have the unit tests inside the same `mod`, but I'm not sure this is the right way to go about it, as I'm mixing two different things.

Should I put my unit tests in a different file? If so, how do I test private methods?

Answer (score 42, accepted):

It's recommended to place tests in their own module. This module should be a child of the module whose code you want to test (and it can be defined in the same or different file).

```
#[cfg(test)]
mod tests {
    #[test]
    fn test_some_stuff() {
      // ... test code ...
    }
}
```

Private methods are not private to child modules, but you still need to import them with `use super::some_name;`.

By the way, this is all explained in the [test organization](https://doc.rust-lang.org/book/ch11-03-test-organization.html) section (11.3) of the Rust Book.

Comment: Can you provide a directory structure as example?

Comment: @EduBic literally just `src/the_file_with_code_and_tests.rs`

Answer (score 0):

There are different possibilities for Unit Tests in Rust.

You have this directory structure:

```
project_name/
    src/
       file.rs
       main.rs || lib.rs
    cargo.toml
```

#### Same file: simple and recommended

In Rust a file is module but you can declare a module inside a file with the `mod` keyword, children module can access parent private code (ex. `your_function()`):

```
fn your_function() {
    //...
}

#[cfg(test)]
mod tests {
    #[test]
    fn your_function_test() {}
}
```

#### Separate files hence modules

In your `main.rs` or `lib.rs` you declare the two modules

```
mod file;
#[cfg(test);
mod tests;
```

Then in your `file.rs`:

```
// !!! pub function since they are sibling modules 
// and by default in Rust all is private !!!
pub fn your_function() {
    //...
}
```

And in the `tests.rs`:

```
#[test]
fn your_function_test() {
    // ...
}
```

The concepts are practically the same, when you learn how Rust manages modules it's all easy. You just put a macro on top of the module declaration and that module is your test module. Different story for the integration tests.